# Using having clause to select multiple values

Tags: sql, group-by, having

in my table I have exams (exam_key) that patients (patient_key) had in hospital with date (exam_date). There are several queries I need to perform:

1. Total amount of studies and patients by year. This is relatively simple and works:

> ```
> select count(exam_key) as TOTAL_EXAMS, count(distinct(patient_key)) as TOTAL_PATIENTS, 
> year(procedure_start) as EXAM_YEAR
> FROM hospitals
> group by year(procedure_start)
> order by year(procedure_start)
> ```

2. Now I need to do the same but only for patients that had >2 exams. Here what I tried

> ```
> select count(exam_key) as TOTAL_EXAMS, count(distinct(patient_key)) as TOTAL_PATIENTS, 
> year(procedure_start) as EXAM_YEAR
> FROM hospitals
> group by year(procedure_start), patient_key having count(exam_key)>2
> order by year(procedure_start)
> ```

But this will only show each single patient with corresponding amount of studies like that

Total_Patients  Total_studies   YEAR_

1          3            2013

1                     5         2013

How can I group this by sum or count of patient_key having count(exam_key)>2 ?
Because

> `group by year(procedure_start), count(patient_key having count(exam_key)>2)`

doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select EXAM_YEAR, sum(TOTAL_PATIENTS) as TOTAL_PATIENTS, sum(TOTAL_EXAMS) as TOTAL_EXAMS from (
    select count(exam_key) as TOTAL_EXAMS, count(distinct(patient_key)) as TOTAL_PATIENTS, 
    year(procedure_start) as EXAM_YEAR
    FROM hospitals
    group by year(procedure_start), patient_key having count(exam_key)>2
)
group by EXAM_YEAR
order by EXAM_YEAR
```

Comment: nope, didn't work